# What's the best way to deploy localization resource files with Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, localization

For my *.resx files in App_GlobalResouces, what should the Build Action be? The defaults for creating a new resource file have Build Action as "Content", Copy to Output Directory as "Do not copy", and Custom Tool as "GlobalResourceProxyGenerator".

On certain servers I get an runtime error: "CS0101: The namespace 'Resources' already contains a definition..." that points to a "temporary asp.net files" folder. This makes me think that maybe I should be embedding these files so I don't have to worry about this duplicate registration. Or is my error the only real problem and keeping the physical files in the App_GlobalResouces section is fine?

Comment: Mine are set to the same thing and it "works on my machine". Did you make sure every single one is set to that?

Comment: Yeah- it works locally, just not on our dev server. It also works on our staging server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it was a trick question. We had a custom culture that wasn't installed that was causing the error. We wrote a quick console app to install the culture on the necessary machines and then the error went away.